# How to get API data using fetch in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, use-effect

I have this api which is returning arrays of values:

```
app.get("/events", (req, res) => {
  let response = null;
  let authObj = auth.authorize();

  setTimeout(() => {
    let result = controller.listEvents(authObj);

    result.then((data) => {
      response = data;
      console.log(data)
      res.json(response); // is this way of passing this data object to front-end right ???
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

the result of `console.log(data)` above looks like below:

```
[
  {
    kind: 'calendar#event',
    etag: '"3203302285276000"',
    id: '69jte9qmoij84irjf2ktlqlqcd',
    status: 'confirmed',
    htmlLink: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NjlqdGU5cW1vaWo4NGlyamYya3RscWxxY2QgYmFudWthamFuYW5hdGhqYXlhcmF0aG5hQG0',
    created: '2020-10-02T15:05:42.000Z',
    updated: '2020-10-02T15:05:42.638Z',
    summary: 'What’s New in Lens 3.6.0',
  },
  {
    kind: 'calendar#event',
    etag: '"3200206562152000"',
    id: '_6l6jehjbbtol8him9194uqr88907cjaoct3japrle5a3ii9o6ds62t3kcln68pb5',
    status: 'confirmed',
    htmlLink: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=XzZsNmplaGpiYnRvbDhoaW05MTk0dXFyODg5MDdjamFvY3QzamFwcmxlNWEzaWk5bzZkczYydDNrY2xuNjhwYjUgYmFudWthamFuYW5hdGhqYXlhcmF0aG5hQG0',
    created: '2020-09-14T17:07:55.000Z',
    updated: '2020-09-14T17:08:01.076Z',
    summary: 'Ansible Contributor Summit - New Contributor Workshops',
   
  }
]
```

And I want to pass this `data` to my front-end and iterate over it to display the `summary`, `status`.

Here's how I get this value to my front-end:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/events").then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setData(res.data);
    });
  });
```

But when I try to print `data` it gives `undefined`

Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter is a Response. It is not the result of the request, it only contains the headers. You need

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/events").then(res => res.json()).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setData(res);
    });
  }, []);
```

Remember the empty dependency array. You don't want to fetch every time the component renders, only once.

The result doesn't have a data property, it's just an array. So use `setData(res);`, not `setData(res.data);`

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot, because you are expecting json

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/events").then((res) => {  
    return res.json()
    }).then((responseJson) => {
       console.log(responseJson);
    });
  
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, but where should I set the `setData` ?

Comment: You could set the data where i console logged responseJson, check out that object and set the data there

Comment: Okay, and how can I access the `summary` and `status` from that jason object? `{data.map(function (item, i) {
        return <li key={i}>{item.summary}</li>;
      })}` like this?